# Vim: commands start with g

Tags: vim

I can't remember from where I know that `g,` and `g;` go back to some sort of "previous places", what is the actual meaning of them?

I tried to look up in `:help normal-index` but couldn't find them, where can I get the documentation?

What would be the closest approach to "go back to the line where my cursor stay 5 seconds or more"

Comment: maybe you find more information with `:h g`

Comment: Learning how to use (and getting into the habit of using) vim's documentation will be far more valuable to you in the long run than asking random strangers what a couple of odd commands do. Especially considering how it is easy to look up that info yourself. I suggest you start with `:help`.

Comment: Continue reading `:h normal-index`. Section 2.4 is called `Commands starting with 'g'` (Where normal-index is Section 2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `:help` on any command. Using `wildmode` and tab completion makes it easier.

`:h g,`

and

`:h g;`

bring up motion.txt and jump to those commands. `g,` and `g;` jump back and forward in the change list (where the last changes to the text were made).

Maybe using the jump list is closer to what you want? `CTRL-O` and `CTRL-I` move through the jump list.

Answer (score 2):

`g;` : goes to the PREVIOUS position in your Change List.

`g,` : goes to the NEXT position in your Change List.

Very usefull!